# No such module 'Alamofire' in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got the project folder from iOS developer.
I try to 'Archive' this to the app store, but there is an error.

the error is "No Such Module 'Alamofire' ~ "

I've looked at a lot of Stack Overflows.
I think my project has a different directory.

iOS developer can't even ask what the problem is because they haven't been contacted. Who can see what's wrong?

Many of the answers say "podfile," but there is no file named podfile in my project directory, but instead in the pods folder.Only xccconfig files exist.

The project folder structure is

= APPLICATION

== APPLICATION

== APPLICATION Tests

== Pods

and

in pods Folder has two file

1. ( Pods-APPLICATION.debug.xcconfig ),
2. ( Pods-APPLICATION.release.xcconfig )

The content is as follows:

```
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Alamofire"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework/Headers"
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "Alamofire"
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -D COCOAPODS
PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible that the project you got doesn't include the Alamofire pod.
open terminal go to the directory of the Project and open the pods w\

```
open Podfile -a Xcode
```

check if the Alamofire pod is in the file, if not write the following

```
pod 'Alamofire'
```

save the file and write

```
pod install
```

in the terminal

if the Alamofire is already in the pod file then type

```
pod update
```

in the terminal, and that should solve your problem.

in case your Project doesn't have a Podfile use

```
pod init
```

that will create a Podfile in your project directory.